# Howto inject Picocli parsed parameters into Spring Bean definitions?

Tags: spring-boot, picocli

I'm trying to use [Picocli](https://github.com/kakawait/picocli-spring-boot-starter) with Spring Boot 2.2 to pass command line parameters to a Spring Bean, but not sure how to structure this.  For example, I have the following `@Command` to specify a connection username and password from the command line, however, want to use those params to define a Bean:

```
@Component
@CommandLine.Command
public class ClearJdoCommand extends HelpAwarePicocliCommand {
    @CommandLine.Option(names={"-u", "--username"}, description = "Username to connect to MQ")
    String username;

    @CommandLine.Option(names={"-p", "--password"}, description = "Password to connect to MQ")
    String password;

    @Autowired
    JMSMessagePublisherBean jmsMessagePublisher;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        jmsMessagePublisher.publishMessage( "Test Message");
    }
}


@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public InitialContext getJndiContext() throws NamingException {
        // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
        final Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }

    @Bean
    public JMSPublisherBean getJmsPublisher(InitialContext ctx){
        return new JMSPublisherBean(ctx);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck in a bit of a circular loop here.  I need the command-line username/password to instantiate my JMSPublisherBean, but these are only available at runtime and not available at startup.

I have managed to get around the issue by using Lazy intialization, injecting the `ClearJdoCommand` bean into the Configuration bean and retrieving the JMSPublisherBean in my `run()` from the Spring context, but that seems like an ugly hack.  Additionally, it forces all my beans to be Lazy, which is not my preference.

Is there another/better approach to accomplish this?

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, but note that the kakawait plugin has been superseded with https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 3):

Second option might be to use pure PicoCli (not PicoCli spring boot starter) and let it run command; command will not be Spring bean and will only be used to validate parameters.

In its `call` method, `Command` would create `SpringApplication`, populate it with properties (via `setDefaultProperties` or using JVM `System.setProperty` - difference is that environment variables will overwrite default properties while system properties have higher priority).

```
  @Override
  public Integer call() {
    var application = new SpringApplication(MySpringConfiguration.class);
    application.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
    System.setProperty("my.property.first", propertyFirst);
    System.setProperty("my.property.second", propertySecond);
    try (var context = application.run()) {
      var myBean = context.getBean(MyBean.class);
      myBean.run(propertyThird);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

This way, PicoCli will validate input, provide help etc. but you can control configuration of Spring Boot application. You can even use different Spring configurations for different commands. I believe this approach is more natural then passing all properties to `CommandLineRunner` in Spring container

Answer (score 1):

One idea that may be useful is to parse the command line in 2 passes:

1. the first pass is just to pick up the information needed for configuration/initialization
2. in the second pass we pick up additional options and execute the application

To implement this, I would create a separate class that "duplicates" the options that are needed for configuration. This class would have an `@Unmatched` field for the remaining args, so they are ignored by picocli. For example:

```java
class Security {
    @Option(names={"-u", "--username"})
    static String username;

    @Option(names={"-p", "--password"}, interactive = true, arity = "0..1")
    static String password;

    @Unmatched List<String> ignored;
}
```

In the first pass, we just want to extract the username/password info, we don't want to execute the application just yet. We can use the [`CommandLine.parseArgs`](https://picocli.info/apidocs/picocli/CommandLine.html#parseArgs-java.lang.String...-) or [`CommandLine.populateCommand`](https://picocli.info/apidocs/picocli/CommandLine.html#populateCommand-T-java.lang.String...-) methods for that.

So, our `main` method can look something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  // use either populateCommand or parseArgs
  Security security = CommandLine.populateCommand(new Security(), args); 
  if (security.username == null || security.password == null) {
      System.err.println("Missing required user name or password");
      new CommandLine(new ClearJdoCommand()).usage(System.err);
      System.exit(CommandLine.ExitCode.USAGE);
  }

  // remainder of your normal main method here, something like this?
  System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(MySpringApp.class, args)));
}
```

I would still keep (duplicate) the usage and password options in the `ClearJdoCommand` class, so the application can print a nice usage help message when needed.

Note that I made the fields in the `Security` class `static`.
This is a workaround (hack?) that allows us to pass information to the `getJndiContext` method.

```java
@Bean
public InitialContext getJndiContext() throws NamingException {
    // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, Security.username); // use info from 1st pass
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Security.password);
    return new InitialContext(env);
}
```

There is probably a better way to pass information to this method.
Any Spring experts willing to jump in and show us a nicer alternative?